# Can't query logged on users on terminal server | qwinsta.exe: Access is denied

Tags: windows-server-2016, terminal-server

On a Windows 2016 terminal server I **can't query the logged on users** (even as domain administrator). In `task manager` the `users` tab is empty.

Using `qwinsta.exe` I get:

```
Error 5 getting sessionnames
Error [5]:Access is denied.
```

I know this may happen when I query a remote computer and `AllowRemoteRPC` is disabled. But here I'm logged on locally and `AllowRemoteRPC` is enabled.

Comment: If you find the solution i'd behappy to hear about :-)

Comment: @bjoster I asked also on Superuser (https://superuser.com/q/1390179/339147). Maybe I have to delete it here.